# Getting InvalidConfigurationException in JGit while pulling remote branch

Tags: java, config, jgit

I'm trying to pull the remote master branch in my currently checked out local branch. Here's the code for it

```
checkout.setName(branchName).call();
PullCommand pullCommand = git.pull();
System.out.println("Pulling master into " + branchName + "...");
StoredConfig config = git.getRepository().getConfig();
config.setString("branch", "master", "merge", "refs/heads/master");
pullCommand.setRemote("https://github.com/blackblood/TattooShop.git");
pullCommand.setRemoteBranchName("master");
pullResult = pullCommand.setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).call();
```

When I run the code I get the following error on this line `pullCommand.setRemote("https://github.com/blackblood/TattooShop.git");`

Error :

```
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.InvalidConfigurationException: 
No value for key remote.https://github.com/blackblood/TattooShop.git.url found in configurationCouldn't pull from remote. Terminating...
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.PullCommand.call(PullCommand.java:247)
at upload_gen.Launcher.updateFromRemote(Launcher.java:179)
at upload_gen.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:62)
```

Following are the contents of my .git/config file

```
[core]
  repositoryformatversion = 0
  filemode = false
  bare = false
  logallrefupdates = true
  symlinks = false
  ignorecase = true
  hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[remote "origin"]
  url = https://github.com/blackblood/TattooShop.git
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
  remote = origin
  merge = refs/heads/master
[remote "heroku"]
  url = git@heroku.com:tattooshop.git
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in JGit. According to the JavaDoc of `setRemote()`, it sets the *remote (**uri or name**) to be used for the pull operation* but apparently only the remote name works.

Given your configuration you can work around the issue by using the remote name like this:

```
pullCommand.setRemote( "origin" );
```

I recommend to open a [bug report](https://eclipse.org/jgit/support/) in the JGit bugzilla so that this gets fixed in future versions of JGit.

Comment: Hmm..actually I removed the setRemote() method call and ran the program which gave me another error which got solved by adding the jsch jar file to my build path. But you're right, this still might be a bug

Comment: If you do not explicitly `setRemote()` the default remote (origin) will be used (see the JavaDoc). That's why removing the call works in your case. But again, I think this is a bug that should be reported.